# Как удалить из массива пустые элементы?

Tags: массивы, java

Есть массив, в него я записываю несколько элементов, количество этих элементов всегда разное.

Что находится в тех ячейках массива, в которые я ничего не записываю?

И как провести с массивом операцию аналогичную `ArrayList.trimmToSize()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Лучше использовать ArrayList, еще лучше стек или очередь, а пустом массиве null, или последняя информация которую ты записал. Обычные массивы не тримятся, разве что заново создавать (пересоздавать) новый.

Comment: null будет только в том случае, если этом массив из объектов - в случае же примитивных типов (int, double, и т.д.) пустые элементы будет нулями

Comment: Не вижу проблем с ArrayList. Да вообще не понятно " т.к. не известен будущий (конечный) размер,", так как это проблема массива - это надо инициировать с размером сразу

Comment: так если я не знаю сколько будет элементов, как инициализировать с размером сразу?

Беру максимальный размер. и потом нужно от него отрезать.

Comment: не понимаю проблемы, ее тут нет. опиши подробнее.

Comment: есть проект, в нем есть много окон (проект написан по архитектуре MVC), каждое окно в коде реализовано к View, окна разные. Необходимо из каждого окна достать определенные элементы.

Для этого я беру reflections, метод getDeclaratedFields(), и достаю все поля, из них отсеиваю те которые мне нужны.

Так вот я хочу записать эти поля, после отсеивания в 1у структуру. 

Хотелось для этого использовать массив, сейчас уже немного передумал, и думаю что буду использовать двумерный массив. Вот думаю как это красивее написать, чтобы не было хардкода.

Comment: так ты же не знаешь сколько окон во вьюхе? как ты создаешь массив? тебе надо использовать арейЛист, у него много полезных методов

Comment: Я бы его использовал, но операция увлечения длинны ArrayList очень длинная, собственно по этому я и ищу обходные решения.

Comment: кто тебе такое сказал? это искусственная проблема, которую ты сам себе придумал =)

Comment: ок, спасибо)
Вообще я нуп конечно)